# Remvove borders from icons on windows 11

Tags: windows, icons, border

I cannot find how to remove white borders from pdf icons. See image:

[image]

Comment: Try small icons and see if the white border goes away.  Nothing like that on my own Windows 11 machines.  Also run DISM and SFC. (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Windows 11 PDF icons are probably handled by an [icon handler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-icon-handlers).  They are probably not editable unless you replace them all with a single icon.

Comment: Try the small icons and 100% scale. Icons for PDF files are showing up correctly here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try a different PDF reader if you’re not satisfied with the preview features!

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings in Windows 11.
Click on Personalization.
Click the Colors page on the right side.
Turn off the Show accent color on title bars and windows borders toggle switch.
Remove accent color pixel border.